# Debugging task-pane Apps for Office

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, ms-office, apps-for-office

I am trying to debug my App for Office, which is running in a task-pane of Microsoft Excel. I am running this with Visual Studio 2012. The functionality I want is simple - since all Apps for Office is creating is an Internet Explorer task pane, would it be possible to inspect the CSS acting on each HTML element, in a way similar to how Firebug works ?

It would be really useful to be able to click on an HTML element, and know what CSS is acting on this element automatically. Especially for large scale projects.

Does anyone know how this might be possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon,
If I understand what you're asking, in Visual Studio 2012, you can use the **Page Inspector** tool. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the .html page for your task pane app, and select **Page Inspector** and then click **Inspect**. You can then see the relevant CSS for the object you've clicked on in the page.